# In protractor test is there a way to wait between test run

Tags: protractor

In protractor, is there a way to add explicit wait between each test run, which has the same effect as Thread.sleep in Java?

Answer (score 12):

you could either start protractor in debug mode

run `protractor debug debugging/yourConfigFile.js`

and add `browser.debugger();` in your test spec where you want it to stop

[here a link to the debugging docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)

or just use `browser.sleep(valueInMilliSeconds);`