# Debugging Protractor / Jasmine tests: Line breakpoints do work, but changes not yet visible in the browser

Tags: debugging, jasmine, protractor

Obviously I miss a few elementary pointers to understand what's going on and how things are working in Jasmine / Protractor tests. Assume the following test:

```
it('should redirect to the start page after login', function() {
    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('user');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('pass');
    element(by.partialButtonText('Login')).click();

    expect(ptor.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/home/); // <line breakpoint here>
});
```

When I debug this using IntelliJ IDEA / Webstorm and set a breakpoint at the `expect`-Line, the execution stops but nothing has happened in the Chrome browser opened by Protractor.

On continuing the execution, the actual test is performed *after the line breakpoint* and the expectations are evaluated correctly.

Where does this asynchronous behavior come from? Is this a Jasmine or a Protractor behavior. 
And is it possible to inspect the situation at the time where the expectation is actually evaluated?

Comment: hey, you can use protractors built-in debugger. i answered a sminlar question here: [In protractor test is there a way to wait between test run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301587/in-protractor-test-is-there-a-way-to-wait-between-test-run)

Comment: @nilsK Thanks! I'm aware of this feature but a) I want to understand how it works and b) rather stick to the comfort & guidance of a full IDE for inspecting & debugging.

Comment: I found a [explanation of this behavior in the Protactor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md): _WebDriverJS maintains a queue of pending promises [...] Protractor adapts Jasmine so that each spec automatically waits [...] before exiting. Jasmine expectations are also adapted to understand promises. [..]  the [Jasmine] code actually adds an expectation task to the control flow [instead of executing them inline]._