# wait for a few seconds before running next step protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

What function do you use to wait for a few seconds before running next step in protractor.  I have a span with a text and I want to wait for the text to be changed from an external source before I check for it again.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
    <button type="submit" onclick="promptTransaction()">Load Transaction</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="handleMessage()">Post Message</button>
    <select name="messageType" class="messageType">
        <option>Submit</option>
        <option>Amount</option>
    </select>
    <div class="message-box"><b>Sending message to hosted page:</b><span class="message-out">waiting...</span></div>
    <div class="message-box"><b>Receiving message from hosted page:</b><span class="message-in">waiting...</span></div>
</div>
```

so when I click the 'post message' button, I should receive a new text from external source and change the span with a classname 'message-in'.

Currently, my test looks like this:

```
        element(by.cssContainingText('button','Post Message')).click().then(function() {

            //WAIT FOR 10 seconds

            element(by.css('.message-box .message-in')).getText().then(function (text) {
                var response = JSON.parse(text);

                expect(response.type).toBe('msax-cc-result');
                expect(response.value.Transaction).toBe('Tokenize');
                expect(response.value.CardToken).not.null();
            })
        });
```

Also, in the text result that is returned from external source, I converted it to json object, but can't since there is a '\'  on it, is there a way to remove it before converting it into an object.

passed data:

```
{"type":"msax-cc-result","value":"{\"Transaction\":\"Tokenize\",\"CardToken\":\"ba9c609f-45fc-49aa-b8b2-ecaffbc56d43\"}"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In protractor test is there a way to wait between test run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301587/in-protractor-test-is-there-a-way-to-wait-between-test-run)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually this is [`browser.sleep(N)`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep), but it is generally speaking not recommended to introduce hardcode delays between browser actions. A better mechanism is an Explicit Wait - waiting for a specific condition to be met on a page using [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) which would periodically check the expected condition status until a timeout happens. Comparing to `browser.sleep()`, `browser.wait()` would stop waiting *immediately* after the wait condition becomes truthy.

For instance, if you know what text to wait for,[`textToBePresentInElement`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement) should fit:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = $(".message-out");
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(elm, "Some message"), 5000);
```

Or, you may for instance, wait for `waiting...` not to be present in element:

```
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.textToBePresentInElement(elm, "waiting...")), 5000);
```

where `5000` is a timeout in milliseconds.

Comment: This solution is great, the browser really waits, but the next steps in protractor goes on. Seems that it is asynchronous command. How could we make protractor wait with next steps too?

Comment: Thanks for this. I did notice a side effect running on SauceLabs the rendering on their side takes a bit of time beetween loading screen and the element being presented. On certain browsers there is not even a loading screen captured, in any case this seems probably related to Selenium drivers.